# Outside temperature vs recommended oil viscocity

Tags: honda, motorcycle, oil

Recommended oil viscosity is 10W30 for my motorcycle but temperature outside is getting higher these days it reaches upto 38 degrees on some days.Is is fine to continue to use 10w30 grade oil or I can switch to 10w40 grade oil without side effects

Comment: Don't switch, The oil temperature when the engine is hot is much higher than the air temperature - it should be around 100C to 120C. Switching might not have any seriously bad side effects, but it definitely won't have any *good* side effects.

Comment: Basically a duplicate: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/12597/10976